# iphone - hiding UIToolbar issue

Tags: iphone, uitoolbar

I have looked at other answers and wrote the codes like that:

```
-(IBAction)tbutton:(id)sender
{
tb1 = [[[UIToolbar alloc] init] autorelease];
tb2 = [[[UIToolbar alloc] init] autorelease];   

if (tb1.hidden == YES && tb2.hidden == YES)
{
tb1.hidden = NO;
tb2.hidden = NO;
//toolbars implementation codes here//
}

else 
{
tb1.hidden = YES;
tb2.hidden = YES;
//toolbars implementation codes here//
}
}
```

I dont want to display two toolbars when the app is loaded, but I want the toolbars appear when clicking on UIButton *toolbarbutton´s selector action named tbutton:, but it happens nothing. NSLog showed only "else", not "if"...
I haven´t set Boolean value of tb1. and tb2.hidden anywhere, only in this action function.

I also want the toolbars disappear when clicking on the button and the toolbars are already appeared.

---

EDIT 31 august 2011:

I have followed gamozzii's and Maxner's advice, but I still have same problem. Any solution/suggestion to solve this?

---

EDIT 16 October 2011:

I think it has something to do with alloc, init and autorelease. I will study them whenever I can and post my answer to solve this problem :)

Comment: Please do not post a new question consisting only of a link to an old one. Thanks!

Comment: @Michael I understand, but how to attract people to my problem?

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-do-i-get-attention-for-my-old-unanswered-questions for two techniques.

Answer (score 2):

You are allocating your UIToolbar objects inside your action method?  (or is that a typo).

The default value of the hidden property is NO, so after you allocate the UIToolbar it will have a value of 'NO' for hidden - you will need to explicitly set it to YES to change it to hidden.

I suspect you want to allocate your UIToolbar objects inside your viewDidLoad method and set the hidden property to YES there, then have your action method implemented as above but without the UIToolbar allocation lines.

i.e. in header file

```
IBOutlet UIToolbar *tb1;
IBOutlet UIToolbar *tb2;

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIToolbar *tb1;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIToolbar *tb2;
```

implementation file

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
        self.tb1 = [[UIToolbar alloc] init] autorelease];
        self.tb2 = [[UIToolbar alloc] init] autorelease];
        self.tb1.hidden = YES;
        self.tb2.hidden = YES;
 }

-(IBAction) tbutton:(id)sender {
   if (tb1.hidden == YES && tb2.hidden == YES)
   {
       tb1.hidden = NO;
       tb2.hidden = NO;
       //toolbars implementation codes here//
   }

   else 
   {
       tb1.hidden = YES;
       tb2.hidden = YES;
       //toolbars implementation codes here//
   }
}
```

Comment: Better answer than mine - deleting my answer!

Comment: Thanks. Your codes gave it a step further, but the app chrashes when I click three times on the button, i.e. first the toolbars appear, then disappear and when to appear again on the third click, it crashed.

Comment: Hi again, I tried your method on a new app, and it works, of course. I think I did something wrong with my big toolbars on my another app. I will test it someday, if it works, I will accept your answer.

Comment: To clarify why this works, the code in the original question always created new toolbar objects when the button was tapped. This has the unintended side effect of replacing the existing toolbar objects stored in `tb1` and `tb2` with these new instances. Since new toolbars are not hidden by default, the value of `hidden` was always `NO` when checked in the `if` statement, and the else block was always executed. IOW, the `if` statement was checking the hidden state of the newly created toolbars, instead of the previous toolbars stored in tb1 and tb2.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using `alpha` instead of `hidden`. So `tb1.hidden = YES` becomes `tb.alpha = 0` and `hidden = NO` becomes `alpha = 1`.

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but the app still crashes after the third click.

Comment: By the way, why do you suggest alpha instead of hidden?

Comment: Oh, I did not know that. Can you provide a link?

Comment: A link about that fact regarding .hidden and .alpha?